# Eloquent ORM: How to pass object in Where clause

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I want to fetch records from a table and then pass to other statement in Where clause. Following is my code:

```
$items = $this->where('id','=',$category_id)->delete();
$result = $item_subscriber->where('item_id','IN',items)->delete(); //Is it possible?
```

Answer (score 0):

For a `WHERE IN` you should use the `whereIn()` function. Also `delete()` returns the number of affected rows, so it won't be of much use...

```
$ids = $this->where('id','=',$category_id)->lists('id');
$this->whereIn('id', $ids)->delete();
$item_subscriber->whereIn('item_id', $ids)->delete();
```

For this and more: [Query builder documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects)

Comment: Not sure I did right but should I not call `get()` to fetch Items first?

Comment: Oh yes you're right. Take a look at the updated answer